# Dropdown list (select/option) not working on Firefox mobile (with touch)

Tags: firefox, drop-down-menu, html-select, dropdown, firefox-quantum

I've recently noticed that my dropdown lists stopped working on Firefox mobile browser.

I've done a simple example in a fiddle: 
https://jsfiddle.net/a52jm6h3/8/

```
<select>
<option>1</option>
<option>2</option>
<option>3</option>
<option>4</option>
</select>
```

I'm using Firefox Quantum (57, 64bits) and then use the developer tools to simulate the mobile, when I select a device like Google Nexus 7 (and make sure the Touch Simulation is Enabled) I'm not able to open the Dropdown list.

Does anyone else had a similar issue?

Comment: Did you find out any solution to this issue?

Comment: Found out today, I had the Fastclick.js plugin in my app, disabled it and the dropdowns started working again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this problem, I was using Fastclick.js (https://github.com/ftlabs/fastclick) plugin in my app.

Just disabled it and the problem was solved. 
Seems like the mobile browsers don't need these kind of plugins nowadays anyway.